# Macbook Pro -> LCD TV wireless display options?

Tags: display, macbook-pro, tv

I have a 2011 Macbook Pro which is running Lion (can upgrade to Mountain Lion if needed), and an LG LCD TV which is connected to and controlled via a Windows PC. At times when I'm using my Macbook in the living room it would be nice to use the TV as a wireless 2nd monitor - what is a reliable way to achieve this? (either hardware, software, or both...)

I care less about video-streaming quality - the quality and latency just needs to be acceptable for typical web browsing.

I'm aware of AirPlay via installing an AppleTV, but I'm already very satisfied with my Windows setup and have no interest in using AppleTV as my main media center. Whatever the solution is, the TV display connection needs to be easily swapped between my Macbook and the connected PC.

Answer (score 0):

This seems roundabout, but you could try using [AirParrot](http://airparrot.com/) to share your MBP's screen/audio and then receive it with [AirServer](http://www.airserverapp.com/en) on the Windows PC.  Otherwise, a VNC server and client might do what you want?